# Pm2 reload not working unless pm2 kill is executed

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a node server managed by pm2.

Whenever code changes I ran the command

> pm2 reload config.json --env staging

but the changes are not reflected until I run the command

> pm2 kill

manually on the server.

Pm2 watch is off in my case.

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been fixed with the latest pm2 version (3.2.3). If it's still the case with the latest pm2 version, please share your ecosystem.config.js file

Comment: I've just observed the same issue with v3.2.9

Comment: I have v. 4.5.0 and still observe the same issue. I have to `pm2 delete <app> && pm2 start <app>.json`. The new code is never fetched with reload